# VB6 compile against side-by-side assembly

Tags: com, vb6, com-interop, side-by-side, regfreecom

I have a DLL written in C# and set for COM visibility. I have it setup as a side-by-side assembly and can successfully deploy the application to client PCs registration free. My question is related to the development PC. Is it possible to compile against the DLL in a similar registration-free manner or is registration required on the development machine? I have tried adding the DLL directly though the `Project -> References` menu and get an error stating "Can't add a reference to the specific file." The DLL is sitting in the same directory as the .vbp file and I have tried adding the DLL both with and without the client app manifest being present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have tried adding the DLL directly though the Project -> References menu

That adds a reference to a *type library*.  A type library is a language-independent description of the types in a COM component, VB6 uses it to know how generate efficient code and to provide type checking and auto-completion.  A type library is the exact equivalent of metadata in a .NET assembly.

Traditionally, and the way VB6 did it, the type library was embedded as a resource in a DLL.  So you are probably used to picking a DLL in the dialog.  That however doesn't work so well when the DLL is generated by C#, the type library can only be generated *after* the C# code is compiled.  You have to pick the .tlb file in the VB6 dialog.  The traditional way starts with the COM component being described in the IDL language, the type library can be generated *before* the code is compiled so can easily be embedded in the final DLL.  It is technically possible to do it in C# as well, but the build steps are very laborious and painful, you essentially have to build the DLL twice with different build commands.

The type library for a C# library is normally generated in one of three ways:

- Using Project + Properties, Build tab, "Register for COM interop" option.  This requires VS to run elevated so it can write to the registry.  You start VS elevated by right-clicking its shortcut and picking "Run as Administrator"
- By running Regasm.exe, using the /tlb:filename option.  An alternative for the 1st bullet and necessary if you don't want to run VS elevated for some reason.  Using the /codebase option on your dev machine is also wise to make it work exactly like the 1st bullet and not require putting the DLL into the GAC with gacutil.exe
- By running the Tlbexp.exe utility, the type library exporter for .NET assemblies.  No registration is done, it only generates the .tlb file.

The first bullet is the normal choice and *very* desirable because you can never forget to update the type library this way.  It is perfectly fine on a dev machine since you only really care about reg-free deployment on the user's machine.  You probably got into trouble by not doing this anymore.

Using the 3rd choice is okay and more compatible with your goals, run [Tlbexp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Just keep in mind that you have to do it again when you make changes to your C# code.  Forgetting this once and losing clumps of head-hair trying to figure out why your C# changes don't seem to be effective or getting hard-to-diagnose error codes gives you lots of reasons to consider the 1st bullet again :)  You can emulate the reg-free scenario by running Regasm.exe with the /uninstall option.

Comment: I am not familiar with the details but apparently as of .NET Core 5 some things have changed wrt how typelibs are produced and how .NET DLLs are registered for COM. Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/69483698/3195477