# Use .NET 7 class library in Excel without registering comhost.dll

Tags: c#, excel, vba, .net-core, com

I'm currently calling .NET functions from Excel using VBA following the instructions in [Can I connect a .NET 5 COM interop object with VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69482805/can-i-connect-a-net-5-com-interop-object-with-vb6).

The downside is that I need to register the `comhost.dll` with elevated privileges. Is there a way to avoid the need to register the `comhost.dll`?

Example code:

```cs
// C# / .NET 7
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1;

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("C3B0480C-5C11-47E7-97A0-5D2BD79D7109")]
public class COMInteropTest
{
    public string TestString() => "Hello World";
}
```

```vb
Private Sub test()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("new:{C3B0480C-5C11-47E7-97A0-5D2BD79D7109"}")
    MsgBox obj.TestString()
End Sub
```

I've tried using the RegFree COM method by adding `<EnableRegFreeCom>True</EnableRegFreeCom>` in the `.csproj` and running `dotnet.exe build /p:RegFree=True` but I'm unable to reference the .dll afterwards.

Comment: Regfree is a good solution that should work, but it can be quite difficult to sort it out, you would need to add a manifest to your application to declare the COM object, etc. Otherwise you can register in HKCU instead of HKCR. You can't do that with regsvr32 but you can do it manually with a code similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35789844/403671 (need to adapt to .NET core, you basically don't need Assembly, Class, CodeBase, RuntimeVersion since comhost.dll is a native one)

Comment: Shouldn't the COM object have a default constructor? Also recommend to create the COM interface for the COM object.

Comment: It is only ever regfree when it is done on the client side.  Tinkering with Excel configuration is not a great idea.  Office is invariably supported and maintained by IT staff, they need to know whenever anything changes that could destabilize the Office install.  You let them know by asking them to deploy your addin.  Best to ask your supervisor/boss to relay this need.